# как вызвать окно для выбора внешнего файла в unity c#?

Tags: unity3d

Всем привет! Пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку открывалось окно, в котором мы выбираем путь к json файлу. После этот путь мне нужно сохранить. Никак не могу понять, с помощью чего именно это можно сделать, может ли кто-то подсказать решение? До этого делал с помощью UnityEditor, но после столкнулся с проблемой, что он не работает в приложении.

Answer (score 0):

```
using UnityEditor;

public string GetJsonPath ()
{
    string path = EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel("Choise Json", "Assets/", "json");
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path)) 
        return;
    return FileUtil.GetProjectRelativePath(path);
}
```

Но этот путь будет действителен только в редакторе, не в билде! Более того в билде этого `json` файла не будет поскольку на него никто не ссылается, если он не в `Resource`, но доставание файлов из этого каталога в билде это отдельная песня.

На него нужна ссылка, это можно с помощью типа `TextAsset` (.txt .html .htm .xml .bytes .json .csv .yaml .fnt).

```
[SerializeField] private TextAsset _json;

public void ReadJson () 
{
    Debug.Log(_json.Text);
}
```

Comment: в этом и проблема, мне нужно, чтобы я мог выбирать путь и в билде

Comment: Отредактировал.

Comment: можно же вроде как-то установить Windows Forms в Unity, но я не понимаю как это сделать

Comment: И чем это тебе поможет?

Comment: с помощью него же можно открывать такие окна

Comment: а с помощью чего вообще можно сделать такую механику? Можешь подсказать?

Comment: Открыть окно в билде? Ты вообще игру пишешь? Ты видел игры вызывающие виндовые панели?

Comment: это немного просто другой случай) там нужен файл json с компьютера, в котором будут храниться данные

Comment: они там же обновляются каждую секунду

Comment: ‍♂️‍♀️‍♂️‍♀️‍♂️‍♀️‍♂️‍♀️‍♂️‍♀️

Comment: Нет это именно тот случая с одеванием штанов через голову. Ну обновляются они каждую секунду и что? Зачем их сохранять в файл на диск то каждую секунду? Одна загрузка на входе, одна на выходе и делается это с помощью `PlayerPrefs`.

Comment: там данные со стрима тик тока, они перезаписываются в файл json каждую секунду, мне необходимо брать данные из этого файла и использовать их уже в игре, а так как он находится не в самом проекте, необходимо его находить

Comment: ‍♂️‍♀️‍♂️‍♀️‍♂️‍♀️‍♂️‍♀️‍♂️‍♀️‍♂️‍♀️‍♂️‍♀️‍♂️‍♀️‍♂️‍♀️‍♂️‍♀️ Геймдев 2022, зачем ты наступил.

Comment: ахах, ну да, мне и самому не нравится эта идея, но что есть, то есть)

Comment: Используя `Directory` из `System.IO` можно легко работать с файловой системой, смотреть содержание папок, создавать новые, удалять, вообщем все что можно в любом фолдере. Нужно только реализовать `UI` по это дело. раньше в играх не редко для загрузки/сохраниения можно было выбирать путь и всегда делали под это интерфейс внутри игры, не окнами. Ну и обрисуй этому тикток дЭзайнеру, чего это будет стоить по времени силам.

Comment: понял, большое спасибо)